# Virtual audio device (or stereo mix) to only grab sound from a certain program

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording, audio-streaming

I'm trying to use a certain program through my stereo mix and have only that program go through, while being able to retain the sounds from other applications that I'm currently running. Stereo mix as far as I can see only allows you to transmit all of your application sounds unless they're muted via the mixer or their own internal settings, which isn't going to work for me.

Is there any way to just pass only one specific program through my stereo mix (or a virtual audio driver), while being able to keep all my other sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you are looking for:

[Virtual Audio Cable](http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm) 
As the request is for a virtual audio driver, it's hard for me to say much more than here is a possible link to what you are after.

Comment: That link is a 404. :(

Comment: http://software.muzychenko.net/eng/vac.htm is this the same thing?

Comment: I believe so, I would use the evaluation version to test it of course.  Sorry about the broken link I pulled it from a database.

Comment: Sorry, I already accepted the answer but I just thought of another question right afterwards. Is there any way to make this work if the program I'm using doesn't have the option to play the audio over a certain audio device?

Comment: Buy an external (USB) sound card and have the program export audio through it?

Comment: The program doesn't allow me to choose which audio device the sound plays over. I don't have the ability to go pick up another sound card now anyways.

Comment: It was just a guess as far as playing to a different device...

Comment: I found another program that will allow me to pick the output channel, so I think I can get it to work now. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: I wish I had been more help.